# Echo the current page title inside a get_posts() WordPress function not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to fetch data from another custom post type `books` into the `readers`. I have written the code and the data shows up.

The challenge is that I want to check the echoed data `$c[0]` against the title of the current page.

Whenever I call the `get_the_title()` function I am instead getting the title of the other custom post type `books`. So there is no way I can add an if like so:

```
if (get_the_title()===$c[0]) {
 //The echo code - see echo part of my code
}
```

When I echo the code, it goes into the top part of the page instead of inside the content area. I am suspecting this is the reason why I can't get the page title. I have tried researching on hooking to the content area and tried but I instead get a bunch of errors.

```
<?php

$posts = get_posts(array(
  'numberposts' => 10,
  'post_type' => 'fixtures-results'

));

if($posts)
{

  foreach($posts as $post)
  {
setup_postdata( $post );
$matches  = str_replace("|% ","|%",get_field('fixtures_results'));
    preg_match_all("@[A-z0-9 ./'áàâäãåǻăāąấấặắǎȧạàãáćĉċčççďđḑḋḍdéèêëĕěēęėềẽȩẹéĝ
ğġģǧǵḡĥħȟḣḥḩíìîïĭїĩīįǐĪỊ̣iỊǏĨị̣ịıíĵķǩḱḳļľŀĺĺóòôöõðőŏōỏǒǫȯoøồớòóõöñńņňŉŋǹṅṇ
ŕŗřṙṛśŝşšṡṣşșţťŧțṫṭtúùûüůūűųũŭǔǘǚǜụuưüúŵŷýÿўỹẏỳỵyẙȳẙźżžẑẓḅḟḿṁṃṕṗṽṿḷẁẃẅẉẘ
ẘẋẍÒÓÔÕÖŐǑǪŌȮØÙÚÛǓǗǙǛŨŮŰŲÜỤŪĆĈČÇÀÁÂÃÄÅẠĄĀȦǍÈÉÊËĖĘĚẸẼĒȨḾṀṂŚŜŞŠṠṢŹŻŽẐẒŃŅŇ
ṄṆÑǸḢḤḨĤȞĹĻĽĿŢŤṪṬŖŘṘṚĜĠĢǦǴḠẀẂẄẈŴḊḌḐĎĐÐṔṖĶǨḰḲẊẌṼṾỴỸỲẎŸȲŶÝĴȷḄḞḶŁłÏÎÍÌıİ
ßıs-]+#[^#]+@", $matches, $countries);

    $results = [];
foreach ($countries[0] as $c) {
    $c = explode("#", $c);
    $country_name = $c[0];
    $results[$country_name] = [];
    $params = explode("%", $c[1]);

    foreach ($params as $key) {

    if (!empty($key)) {
      $test = explode("|", trim($key, '|'));

       echo get_the_title($postID);
      //echo $c[0] . $test[0] . $test[1] . $test[2].'<br>';
  
        }


      }   

    }
  
  }
wp_reset_postdata();
}


?>
```

I have tried but can't get past that point. Thanks.

Comment: in your `foreach($posts as $post)` make the first line `setup_postdata( $post );` and remember to `wp_reset_postdata();` after the foreach loop., this will make `get_the_title()` work with the current iterantion of the loop. Else, you could also just pass the postid to `get_the_title()`

Comment: Tried the suggestion but it did not work. I think the first task is to get the code into the content part of the page and not the top of the page as is now. Then maybe the suggestion might work but I don't know how to hook it there without errors.

Comment: We are talking about archive page right ? So you want the title of archive the_title() will return current object title. get_the_title needs post id to return. you can try even get_queried_object() which will hold archive page data in your case. Also what is $postID? Shouldnt be $post->ID ?

Comment: No this is not archive page.  I created two custom post types. I am pulling data from the ```books``` post type into ```readers``` post type. The books post type contains the data but I want to use the title of ```readers``` post type as a condition to only display data IF the title of readers matches the title of the custom post type ```books``` represented by ```$c[0]```